# How to setGenericPassword in Keychain with React-Native?

Tags: react-native, keychain

using the following code somehow it stops reading the lines and I get stuck without solutions. So I am trying to `setGenericPassword` using `react-native-keychain` but the message from console.log that is inside function I can see it and the one after doesn't. So `dispatch()` is not called ever it goes straight to `catch()`

Any idea what is going wrong here?

```
return axios.post(SIGNUP_URL, { email, password }).then((response) => {
  var { user_id, token } = response.data;
  Keychain.setGenericPassword(user_id, token, console.log('I can see this'));
  console.log('I can not see this');
  dispatch(authUser(user_id));
}).catch((error) => {
  dispatch(addAlert("Could not sign up."));
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what ur trying to achieve with `console.log('I can see this')` statement while calling a function. Can you please post what `error` ur getting in `catch` block?

Comment: @PrasunPal with console.log I am trying to check weather the code is build or not. As you can see in catch block the error is "Could not sign up". So as mentioned above soon as I close Keychain function the other lines are skipped until .catch frunction

Comment: You could have print `console.log()` before `Keychain.setGenericPassword`, anyways, what value you are getting in `error`, the error `Could not sign up` is defined by you, I was asking for value `error`.

Comment: @PrasunPal `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNKeychainManager.setGenericPasswordForOptions')` this is the error I get from `error`